# Hosting multiple sites using wordpress and ssl requirements

Tags: wordpress, security, ssl, web

I have a VPS, and I am planning to run a word press instance on it. I want to host sites for different and entirely separate businesses. However, if possible we do not want to pay for a separate SSL certificate for every site.

Is this possible?

Is multisite the answer to this? Assuming that we would have to by a multi domain SSL that right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption is right. You have to get Multi domain (SAN) SSL certificate to protect your multiple domain hosted on differ servers with single certificate. It is too much expensive to get different SSL certs for individual domains, so SAN SSL is an apotheosis option.